# Как найти точку входа?

Tags: exe, теория, pe

Всем привет. Кто нибудь знает, по какому адресу находится OEP во всех Windows программах, ну или как вычисляется?

P.S. Сразу говорю, такие программы как PEID не советовать пожалуйста :)

Comment: Я знаю! OEP во всех Windows программах находится по *разным* адресам. Серьёзно, каждый пакует по разному, трассировать нужно процесс распаковки.

Comment: На а если не OEP, а просто EP ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724306/calculating-the-file-offset-of-a-entry-point-in-a-pe-file